# Exception thrown:'System.DllNotFoundException

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2015

I have this project running on Visual Stuio 2008 with out issue. However when i want to use same DLL in another project build with Visual Studio 2015 it provides Unable to load DLL error.

Has anyone experienced this problem?

Comment: The DLL you're trying to load, is that a DLL you built?  A framework DLL?  Could you share the code that tries to load the DLL?

Comment: Its a DLL built i think. it came with this module. I have the soruce code for VS 2008 it works fine i run the complier however with 2015 it gives error.

Comment: What is the full exact text of the error?

Comment: Exception thrown: 'System.DllNotFoundException' in TELEPHONE SYSTEM.exe

Additional information: Unable to load DLL 'AD101Device.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Comment: Are you linking to this DLL, or are you trying to load it by name?

Comment: this is how i load  [DllImport("AD101Device.dll", EntryPoint = "AD101_InitDevice")]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the DLL is in the same folder as the EXE that you run.  If that doesn't work, try copying the DLL to a commonly-searched folder like `C:\Windows\System32` just to see if that helps.