# System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'AD101Device.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Tags: c#, dll

this question is already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35561602/exception-thrownsystem-dllnotfoundexception) But there's no suitable solution I found.
*I cannot Comment so than I had to ask in a new question.
There's a CallerID device attached with my pc. My application is needed to be hit if any caller calls. I've implemented the procedure. but got stuck with this .dll file.
*I am using Visual Studio Installer Project to create installer file. When I install and run my application I got, `System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'AD101Device.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)` this error.
**Yes I've placed the .dll file on the bin folder.
please enlighten me, how can I overcome this situation with the .dll file working.
*I'm using Visual Studio 2015. .net framework version 4.5.1

Comment: Well, looks like your installer is not good enough.  Most likely cause is it forgetting to copy a DLL that AD101Device.dll needs.  If you can't figure it out from enabling loader snaps or SysInternals' Process Monitor then asking the owner of the DLL for proper deployment instructions is recommended.

Comment: Their, solution works perfectly. I adopted their code into my solution.
please suggest me something how can I make my installer good.

Comment: I've found a solution*. I just needed to attach an assembly of the dll when creating the VS installer project. it binds the dll with project. so than wherever i place the installer file and install, this automatically 
places the dll file into the folder where the application installs.
*this might not be the only solution. there might be a better one